# Calculate percentage difference between statistics of two consecutive date in a dataframe and output the result based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file which contains data for certain dates (**2018-02-11** to **2018-03-14**).

```
,date,location,device,provider,cpu,mem,load,drops,id,latency,gw_latency,upload,download,sap_drops,sap_latency,alert_id
0,2018-02-12 11:52:59.342269+00:00,WEO,10.11.100.1,POP,6.0,23.0,11.75,0.0,,,,,,,,
1,2018-02-13 11:53:04.006971+00:00,COO,10.11.100.1,BOP,6.0,23.0,4.58,0.0,,,,,,,,
2,2018-02-14 11:52:59.342269+00:00,,,COO,,,10.45,,,,,,,,,
3,2018-02-15 09:52:59.342269+00:00,,,DOP,,,12.45,,,,,,,,,
4,2018-02-16 04:52:59.342269+00:00,,,RRE,,,9.45,,,,,,,,,
5,2018-02-17 05:52:59.342269+00:00,,,WEQ,,,5.45,,,,,,,,,
```

Now I want to find the `mean`, `min`, `max` and `std` for two consecutive dates and calculate the percantage difference and check with the threshold value.So for any column value if I find percentage difference to be say **20%** or more, I will post that column value into a csv file.

I have done it for two consecutive dates `2018-02-12` and `2018-02-13` and found out the statistics for each of them and the calculated the percentage difference.Here is my code below

```
df = pd.read_csv("metrics.csv", parse_dates=["date"])

df.set_index("date", inplace=True)

# get the stats for the date 2018-02-12
df_prev = df.loc['2018-02-12'].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

# get the stats for the date 2018-02-13
df_next = df.loc['2018-02-13'].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

# calculate the percentage difference
df_diff_pt = abs(df_next - df_prev.values)/(df_prev.values) * 100
df_diff_pt.to_csv("percentage_diff.csv", index=False)
```

I get the below output

```
cpu cpu cpu cpu mem mem mem mem load    load    load    load    drops   drops   drops   drops   latency latency latency latency gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  gw_latency  upload  upload  upload  upload  download    download    download    download    sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_drops   sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency sap_latency
mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std mean    min max std
20.25266967     9.375   5.406603424 0.5193349753        0   0.5944589255    20.31451491     3.544110148 2.184989728 190.2821256     0   76.67007734 3.85929503  19.89528796 17.31689683 2.697415388 1.680556319 0   19.34731935 4.084268605 14.86356963     23.19968083 10.35004075 24.58650424     7.780228594 9.740543925 4.47444575      0   0.4689312965    0.2667648736    0   29.78723404 14.15288291
```

As you can see for the `cpu mean`, it has jumped the threshold value and so for other metrics as well.

Now I want to do it for every pair of consecutive dates([`2018-02-11, 2018-02-12`], [`2018-02-12, 2018-02-13`]....) and whenever I find for any metric, the stat value is more than the threshold (20%), I append to a csv file and continue the operation.

But with my current approach, I can only manually enter two dates and put the result in a csv file and then further check for threshold breach.This means I will be creating a .csv for every pair of dates.I want to do it on the fly and get one final .csv file with the expected result.How do I do it?

One way is to loop through the dataframe and select the dates and do the comparison

```
for i in df.index:
    for j in pd.to_timedelta(i, unit='D'):
        df_prev = df.loc[i].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

        df_next = df.loc[j].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

        df_diff_pt = abs(df_next - df_prev.values) / (df_prev.values) * 100
        break

    #further operations
```

But I get the below error

```
ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Comment: Can you check my answer? First was removed, but now there are 2 solution.

Comment: @jezrael sorry I had gone out...I will check now and let you know

Comment: Yes, there is problem with last row, I think the best is remove it, because not possible compare with not exist next value datetime for last value of index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think better is create one DataFrame by [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) rows by `1 day`, remove last row because compare with non exist next values and for filter by tresh use [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for check at lease one value per row by condition:

```
df1 = df.resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                     'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                      'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

tresh = 50
df11 = df1.shift(freq='d')
df2 = df1.sub(df11).abs().div(df11, fill_value=1).mul(100).iloc[:-1]
df2 = df2[(df2 > tresh).any(1)]
df2.to_csv("percentage_diff.csv", index=False)
```

Your loop solution should be:

```
dfs = []
for i in np.unique(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))[:-1]:
    j = (pd.Timestamp(i) + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df_prev = df.loc[i].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

    df_next = df.loc[j].resample('D')['cpu', 'mem', 'load', 'drops', 'latency',
                                             'gw_latency', 'upload', 'download', 'sap_drops',
                                             'sap_latency'].agg(['mean', 'min', 'max', 'std']).fillna(0)

    df_diff_pt = abs(df_next - df_prev.values) / (df_prev.values) * 100
    df_diff_pt = df_diff_pt[(df_diff_pt > tresh).any(1)]

    if not df_diff_pt.empty:
        dfs.append(df_diff_pt)
df2 = pd.concat(dfs).to_csv("percentage_diff2.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: I think your first solution works good since indeed any percentage difference above tresh 50 is logged.So its good for me :)

Comment: can you please explain what does this line `df2 = df1.sub(df11).abs().div(df11, fill_value=1).mul(100).iloc[:-1]` do?

Comment: @Souvik Ray I am on pnone only, so a bit complicated, but try.

Comment: It is rewrite your code ` abs(df_next - df_prev.values) / (df_prev.values) ` by pandas aritmetic functions sub for -, div for / and mul for *. Also iloc remove lart row of dataframe

Comment: @SouvikRay - Glad can help!